# Can't Run 'app' in Android studio Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android

I'm a very beginner.. In fact I installed Android Studio a few days ago.
Anyway, when I click Run 'app' it says:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources [Fatal Error] :6:7: Il tipo di elemento "resources" deve terminare con la corrispondente tag finale "< /resources>".

C:\Users\x\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:5:6: Error: Il tipo di elemento "resources" deve terminare con la corrispondente tag finale "< /resources>". :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\x\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml:5:6: Error: Il tipo di elemento "resources" deve terminare con la corrispondente tag finale "< /resources>".

* Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.517 secs
```

And if I go in styles.xml I have:

```
< resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

< /resources>
```

So I don't know.. What's the problem? Help me! :(

Comment: You're closing style with /> so you don't need the </style> tag

Comment: @DavidM you should post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your style is being closed in the line

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
      parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

by the `/>` so the extra `</style>` is looking for an open style tag that doesn't exist. You can delete that or change the `/>` to just `>`

Just as a side note, it would be best if you could post the log file in English.